# proto-loader unable to load .proto file with dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, proto, grpc-node

I'm trying to load .proto files coming from the [arduino-cli](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli) repo. More specifically, I'm loading the [commands.proto](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli/blob/master/rpc/commands/commands.proto) that has a dependency on a few other .proto files within the same directory.

In the load options provided to proto-loader, I specified the paths to all these .proto dependencies, yet an error pops up stating that proto messages defined in one of these dependencies are not defined.

Here is my code:

```
const grpcLib = require('grpc');
const protoLoader = require('@grpc/proto-loader');
const pathLib = require("path");

const RPC_PATH = pathLib.join(__dirname, "arduino-cli/rpc")
var PROTO_PATH = pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/commands.proto");
const options = {
    keepCase: true,
    longs: String,
    enums: String,
    defaults: true,
    oneofs: true,
    includeDirs: 
    [
        pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/common.proto"),
        pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/board.proto"),
        pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/compile.proto"),
        pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/core.proto"),
        pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/upload.proto"),
        pathLib.join(RPC_PATH, "/commands/libs.proto"),
    ]
  }
const packageDefinition = protoLoader.loadSync(PROTO_PATH, options);
```

The last line causes this error:

```
/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:382
        throw Error("no such type: " + path);
        ^

Error: no such type: BoardDetailsReq
    at Service.lookupType (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:382:15)
    at Method.resolve (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/method.js:147:44)
    at Service.resolveAll (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/service.js:111:20)
    at Namespace.resolveAll (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:307:25)
    at Namespace.resolveAll (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:307:25)
    at Namespace.resolveAll (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:307:25)
    at Namespace.resolveAll (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:307:25)
    at Root.resolveAll (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/namespace.js:307:25)
    at Root.resolveAll (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/node_modules/protobufjs/src/root.js:258:43)
    at Object.loadSync (/Users/Herve/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader/build/src/index.js:218:16)
```

The `BoardDetailsReq` message causing the error is defined in [boards.proto](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-cli/blob/master/rpc/commands/board.proto), which is included with the `includeDirs` in my `options` struct. Is this not correct? I must be doing something wrong if this error is happening.

Comment: What version of the `@grpc/proto-loader` library do you have? Did it output any warnings before that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `includeDirs` option is to list directories that should be searched for imported files. The file in question imports `commands/common.proto`, `commands/board.proto`, etc. So `includeDirs` should point to the directory that contains those files. In this case, that is `RPC_PATH`. So, your `includeDirs` list should just be `[RPC_PATH]`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes a lot of sense!